# Combine multiple rows in a single json string MySQL

Tags: mysql, .net-core

Here is my current result:

[image]

I want the result into a single JSON_OBJECT like:

"{"2100": "1739", "2300": "168", ...}"

I am trying the following code.

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(CP.RankID, COUNT(CP.RankID)) -- GROUP_CONCAT(CP.RankID SEPARATOR ',') AS Ranks -- CP.RankID, COUNT(CP.RankID) AS NoOfRank
       FROM CommunityPath AS CP
       GROUP BY CP.RankID;
```

Is there any way to do that.
Basically this will be an SP or Function which will be called for each row from another SP/Query.

**NB: the image result is produced by a CTE.**

Answer (score 0):

Somehow got the solution, If it helps someone

```
SELECT  CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(RN SEPARATOR ',')) AS RankInfo
    FROM (SELECT JSON_OBJECT(CP.RankID, COUNT(CP.RankID)) AS RN FROM CommunityPath AS CP GROUP BY CP.RankID) AS CT
    GROUP BY 'all';
```